# what is the method for WolframAlpha to get the integer solution of indeterminate equation?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, algebra, wolframalpha

To input " 1/x+1/y-1/xy^2 = 3/4 " in wolframalpha ，It can get the integer solution Integer solution: x = 2,y = 3
How it get?

Comment: Are you asking how Wolfram|Alpha calculates it or how normal people calculate it?

Comment: Both,I want to know whether normal people can use the Wolfram|Alpha method.And what is more ,I want to know the Algorithm By what the Wolfram|Alpha calculates it.(Maybe not brute-force method)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because contains no code related question

Answer (score 6):

```
integer solutions 1/x+1/y-1/xy^2 = 3/4
```

But to be honest if you plan on doing intensive math I would strongly consider looking into a math package like [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) or [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/).